# How to call several actions from within another action?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm migrating a non-MVC application to Laravel 4.2 and I'm unsure of the best way to accomplish this task.  I have several reports created on routes like this:

```
/reports/this_report
/reports/that_report
/reports/another_report
```

These actions query the database, run a bunch of calculations, and generate some html tables and forms.

What I need to add now is a page like this:

```
/reports/dashboard
```

This dashboard page should display the output of all 3 reports in a condensed format, each with a "click to view details" link that takes the user to the main report page.

Is there a way for the dashboard action to call each of the report actions, and use their output as data in the dashboard view?

Comment: All you should have to do is call the other report methods from a main method that passes data to the dashboard view. Another tip: You might want to have the reports return an array of data and then put the table/form generation in a view in order to keep logic and templating separate. I'll write up an answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little code of how you would do this. I'm not exactly sure how you have everything structured, so you might have to adapt this a little.

Lets say you have a route for the dashboard like this.

`Route::get('/reports/dashboard', DashboardController@showDashboard');`

This route should call a controller method that will do your processing.

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController 
{

    public function showDashboard()
    {
        return View::make('dashboard')->with(array(
            'report1_data'    => $this->getReport1Data(),
            'report2_data'    => $this->getReport2Data(),
            'report3_data'    => $this->getreport3Data()
        ));
    }

    public function getReport1Data() { //calculations, return array of results }

    public function getReport2Data() { //calculations, return array of results }

    public function getReport3Data() { //calculations, return array of results }

    public function showThisReport()
    {
        $data = $this->getReport1Data();
        return View::make('report')->with(array('data' => $data));
    }

    public function showThatReport()
    {
        $data = $this->getReport2Data();
        return View::make('report')->with(array('data' => $data));
    }

    public function showAnotherReport()
    {
        $data = $this->getReport3Data();
        return View::make('report')->with(array('data' => $data));
    }

}
```

So, this dashboard method will call the other methods (that you will also include in this controller) that will query the database and calculate the reports.

Then it returns a View with all of the data. The view will format the data and display it to the user.

Now, to make it so you can see the detailed view of each report, I suggest adding a couple more methods and routes to show detailed views.

`Route::get('/reports/this_report', 'DashboardController@showThisReport');`
`Route::get('/reports/that_report', 'DashboardController@showThatReport');`
`Route::get('/reports/another_report', 'DashboardController@showAnotherReport');`

I hope this helps! Good luck.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but it's not only the data that I need to include on the main dashboard, it's the HTML produced by the individual report views.  That's why I was hoping to call the individual routes, so I could capture whatever they were doing & outputting and combine it for the dashboard.  I also want to avoid having to update several places with duplicate code ( for example, if the first report moves to getReport1DataB() instead of just getReport1Data() I don't want to have to update showThisReport() and showDashboard().

Comment: Maybe AJAX would be a good option then. Then your javascript could hit each of those routes, get the file contents and display them on your dashboard.